# How to set Import Units when importing a collada file with python script?

Tags: python, collada

Blender shows the python command in the tooltip, for example, hover the mouse over *File > Import > Collada (Default) (.dae)*, it shows:

> Load a Collada file
>   Python: `bpy.ops.wm.collada_import()`

Then I can find the `bpy.ops.wm.collada_import()` command in the script console.

I want to set the **Import Units** to `True` before I import the collada file, hover the mouse over the ticker it says

> Python: `WM_OT_collada_import.import_units`

But I can't find any clue on how to use this piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

`WM_OT_collada_import` is the [bl_idname](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70a_release/info_overview.html#class-registration) of the Collada Import Operator in the C-code notation (in Python it's wm.collada_import, but the importer is a C operator).

`import_units` is an [operator property](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70a_release/bpy.props.html#operator-example).

If you want to set this property to `True` in an operator call, give it a keyword-argument:

```
bpy.ops.wm.collada_import(filepath=..., import_units=True)
```

Comment: I have checked the signature of the python api method bpy.ops.wm.collada_import() but didn't see the import_units=True option. However your solution works like a charm, many thanks to your help!